# How to move array element to begining of array depending on another varible

Tags: php, arrays, element, move

what is the best way to move array element to begining depending another variable as value of array .
for example :

```
$car = 'bmw';
$model = array( '1' => array( 'color' => 'red' ,'model' => 'benz') , '2' =>array('color'=>'black',model'=> 'bmw') );
```

i want to move '2' =>array('color'=>'black','model'=> 'bmw') at begining depending on $car variable .

```
$model = array('2' =>array('color'=>'black','model'=> 'bmw'), '1' => array( 'color' => 'red' , 'model' => 'benz') );
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: what if there would be several "models" `bmw` in the initial array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use array_unshift() function to shift any index to first in array

```
$car = 'bmw';
$model = array( '1' => 'benz' , '2' => 'bmw' , '3' => 'audi');
$key = array_search($car, $model);
if ($key > 0) {
   unset($model[$key]);
   array_unshift($model, $car);
}
```

Comment: You'll use indexes this way, I'm not sure the OP really needs them though

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick and will keep the original keys:

```
<?php

$car = 'bmw';
$models = array('1' => array('color' => 'red', 'model' => 'benz'), '2' => array('color' => 'black', 'model' => 'bmw'), '3' => array('color' => 'green', 'model' => 'audi'));

foreach (array_values($models) as $key => $model) {
  if ($model['model'] == $car) {
    $index = $key;
    break;
  }
}

$models = array_slice($models, $index, 1, true) + array_slice($models, 0, $index, true) + array_slice($models, $index + 1, count($models), true);

var_dump($models);
```